# Buying a game from steam store and using dlc code

Tags: steam

Basically I bought Civilization V pack long ago so that pack didn't contain brave new world dlc. Now I got dlc code and when I try to activate dlc code it tells me to activate main game first eventho I already have Civilization V at my library. So what's wrong here? Do I have to activate main game with code too if I want to add DLC via code? It makes no sense.

Comment: Are you trying to say you bought Civ V from the Steam store and Brave New World from a retailer?

Comment: Try asking steam (if you got it from there) support or the producers of Civilization V/ publishers of Civ V. We can not really help you with this probelm

Comment: Could you show us a copy of your list of subscriptions? [Here's an example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3T9wO.png). You can access it (if logged in) [here](https://store.steampowered.com/account/licenses/).